# Access files in zip before extracting them

Tags: php, zip

How can I validate files in a zip file using `finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE)` before extracting them using `extractTo`?

I am using the ziparchive class: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Comment: Well, since you already have decided for a specific library I would suggest that you take a look into the documentation of that library. That should hold the answer to your question. That documentation reveals: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.getnameindex.php

Comment: @arkascha  I've been.  I think maybe `getFromIndex`, `getFromName`, `getNameIndex`, or `getStream` might hold the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']) === true) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $name=$zip->getNameIndex($i);
        $pieces=explode(DS,$name);
        if(substr($name, -1)==DS) {
            //validate directory structure if desired
        }
        else {
            //validate file
            $mime=$finfo->buffer($zip->getFromIndex($i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, you found a solution yourself. Thanks for sharing!